# Null check for Double/Int Value in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am new in Spark,
How can I check for for Null value in Double and Int value in scala or Spark.

Like for String We can do like this :

```
val value = (FirstString.isEmpty()) match {
          case true => SecondString
          case _    => FirstString
        }
```

I searched for it a lot but i found only for String value. Can you please suggest me for other datatype as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can simply use `Option`s. So like:

```
val d: Double = ...

val isNull = Option(d).isDefined
```

Or you can use pattern matching:

```
val d: Double = ...

Option(d) match {
  case Some(v) => use v
  case _ => you got Null
}
```

Comment: This is pointless: because a `Double` can't be null, `Option(d)` will always be `Some`. If the code in `...` doesn't actually evaluate to a `Double`, but to `java.lang.Double` (which can be null), then you'll get an exception on that line.

Comment: use Try{} instead

Answer (score 6):

null is only applicable for AnyRef (i.e non primitive types) types in Scala. AnyVal types can not be set to null.

For example:

```
// the below are AnyVal(s) and wont compile
val c: Char = null
val i: Int = null
val d: Double = null
```

String is an AnyRef and so can be null:

```
// this is ok!
val c: String = null
```

That's why pattern matching nulls to Int/Double types is not possible:

```
// wont compile!
null match {
        case a:Int => "is a null Int"
        case _ => "something else"
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`isEmpty` is not at all the same as "check for null". Calling `isEmpty` on `null` will fail:

```
val s: String = null
s.isEmpty // throws NullPointerException
```

`Int` and `Double` can't be null (neither can any other primitive types), so there is no need to check if they are. If you are talking specifically about Spark `Row`s, you need to check for null *before* getting an `Int`/`Double`/other primitive value:

> [It is invalid to use the native primitive interface to retrieve a value that is null, instead a user must check isNullAt before attempting to retrieve a value that might be null.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row)